# How do I utilize Android Google Map Capabilities?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-latitude

Okay guys, I am developing an app on Android that uses the Google API to display a map on the screen. I have simple overlays that will display the location of Contacts that the user decides to track. I already know how to use the Mapping and retrieve my own location, but I need to know the best way to get other Users locations.

With the release of Google Latitude's API, this functionality was supposed to be made easy. I cannot find any tutorials or anything on how to implement the API.

Please: If you know any Tutorials or anything of the sort to teach me this, please let me know. Also, if this is not the most efficient way to go about this let me know.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Specs: Eclipse Galileo, Android SDK, Android APIs and Google API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what the Google Latitude App already does?

http://www.google.com/latitude/intro.html

There are also some docs here: http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/getting_started.html

Personally, I'd start by experimenting with the REST API outside of Android to get a sense of how it works.